# How to generate apk by using genexus?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd, genexus-gam

I'm failed to Integrated the three different transaction/ work with device pattern of Genexus. APK files are individually generated. Three apk for three transaction table. how can i develop into a single apk file?

Answer (score 1):

One APK is generated per SmartDevice Main object. You can create many SDPanels, Dashboard and/or WWSD pattern object and how those interact will define what gets included in your APK. Just one of them should be a Main Object, and that's the starting point of your app, your first panel.

Take a look a this [document](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20087,Smart+Devices+objects,) for more info

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to create a dashboard object and make it the Main program with the property `Main program = True`, then all the remaining WWSD, Dashboards, and SDPanels are included like `Actions` for this main dashboard.

> You should check that in the **Main programs** section of Folder View there are only those that you need. The other ones could be removed setting `Main program = False`